# Fetch year portion of multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a SQL table called "picturevents". In there are all events stored to which pictures exist.

I would now like to implement a dropdown on my page, where the user can select the year from which he would like to have the pictures displayed. 
For this I need to receive all years from my database.

I now have the following function in my php script (which works perfectly fine):

```
function getPictureYears(){

    $ret = mysqli_query($this->link, "SELECT `id` FROM `pictureevents` WHERE 1");
    $array = null;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($ret, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        $array[] = $row;
    }

    for($i=0; $i < sizeof($array); ++$i){
        $id = $array[$i]['id'];
        $array[$i]["year"] = mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($this->link, "SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ( SELECT `date` FROM `pictureevents` WHERE `id` = $id))"))[0];
    }
    return $array;  
}
```

I would be happy if I could simplify it.
I found the following function:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM (SELECT `date` FROM `pictureevents` WHERE 1))
```

This works great as long as the subquery only returns one row, when there is more than one row in the table, SQL reports:

```
     1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

How can I get around the error, but still doing everything "in SQL"? Is it even possible?

BTW: The reason why I always try to do as much as possible in SQL is: their code is much more sophisticated than what I could ever write and it simplifies my code very much.

Comment: Is your subquery expected to return only one unique value?  If so, try `SELECT DISTINCT DATE FROM ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT distinct year(`date`) FROM `pictureevents`
```

Returns all years (every year once) for which entries in `pictureevents` exist.

Comment: Nice, solved my proble, thank you very much
(Will flag it as solution as soon as I can;))